# DRF: Image vs Field naming

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

On my model, I have fields like `photo = models.ImageField()`– practically this means I can upload and set images from the admin; but from the DRF Serializer it feels more appropriate to suffix URL: `photo_url = serializers.ImageField()`

Is there a standard way of doing this in a DRF-y way here? I could of course make the `photo` on my model into `photo_url`, but that feels a bit strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in serializer validate method. For example:

```
class YourSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    photo_url = serializers.ImageField()

    class Meta:
        model = YourModel
        fields = [] #your model fields

    def validate(self,attrs):
        attrs['photo'] = attrs['photo_url']
        return attrs
```